# Why is it singular?

Tags: grammar

> In 1787 America was a new nation. Most of the territory was a
>   wilderness.

In the second sentence, most of the territory is singular. Why is it singular?

Comment: Most of the pie *is* gone. It *was* cut into eight pieces, and six pieces *were* eaten.  A  "territory", like pie, is a single undivided whole (until it becomes parceled out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With words that indicate portions( *a lot, a majority, some, all,most of* we are guided by the noun after **of**. If the noun after of is singular, use a singular verb. If it is plural, use a plural verb.

> Most of the territory **was** a wilderness.

With collective nouns such as group, jury, family, audience, population, the verb might be singular or plural, depending on the writer's intent.

> Most of the group was/were here.